# is the DOM an API, or is the API part of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, api, dom

I read that API's are used to manipulate the DOM, then I read somewhere else that the DOM is an example of an API, how does the dom and api's fit together?

Comment: It depends how you define API.

Comment: it's an API of APIs.

Comment: If you are talking about the standards, then DOM is an API.
If you are talking about HTML browser creating DOM then it is an object. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) for more info.

Comment: There's the `DOM` and there are `API's` to manipulate the `DOM`, which are called `DOM api's`

Comment: But there are more `API's` than `DOM api's` on the web there all part of `Web API's`

Comment: The `DOM` has an `API` to access and manipulate it, the `DOM` itself is not an `API`